# bind C++ virtual methods to js with override capability

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, node-modules

Assume I have a C++ class:

```
class cRenderer {
    ...
    virtual void draw();
    ...
}
```

This is part of a render engine, so any C++ class that inherits *`cRenderer`* can override the *`draw`* method and have stuff drawn on the screen.

The question is how can I implement the same behavior with v8 bindings (This is going to be eventually a Node.js module)?

One might say, I can do this:

```
class cApplication : public cRenderer, public node::ObjectWrap
{
    ... define bindings ...
}
```

Then in my javascript I do something like:

```
var app = new cApplication();
var oldDraw = app.draw; //saving old instance of draw
app.draw = function() {
    ... do drawing api calls ...
    oldDraw(); //calling old draw
}
```

That's not going to work because all drawing api calls are happening outside of *`draw`*.

More specifically, how can JS bindings insert dynamic api calls inside the *`draw`* method? How one can tackle this issue? Please bare in mind, editing the architecture of the render engine is not an option.

**EDIT:**

By outside and inside of *`draw`* I meant:

```
drawCircle(100, 100, 11); //outside of render loop
draw(); //nothing happens at this point.
```

But if you had your call inside the draw method:

```
void draw()
{
    //inside of render loop
    drawCircle(100, 100, 11); //it draws a circle at (100, 100) with radius 11
}
```

Comment: Could you decipher this "Tall drawing api calls are happening outside of draw.". What are "inside" and "outside" here?

Comment: @c-smile I did, please consider my edit.

Comment: You should have some entity representing rendering surface - usually it sort of Graphics object. Your `void draw(gfx)` shall receive it as a parameter. And so it can invoke: `gfx.drawCircle(100, 100, 11)`.

Answer (score -1):

My [Sciter](http://www.terrainformatica.com/sciter/) engine uses so called immediate model of drawing. I highly suspect that you are trying to do the same here.

Immediate model of drawing:

Any DOM element in Sciter may have "paint handlers" attached to it:

```
var someEl = ...

someEl.paintBackground = function(gfx) {... }
someEl.paintContent = function(gfx) {... }
...
```

Such painters will be invoked by native code when the element needs to be drawn. 
Just in case, in HTML/CSS element drawing is split on multiple layers: background, content, foreground/outline.

Here is how native draw_background is implemented for example:

```
class Element {

   void draw_background(graphics* gfx) {
      if( has_paintBackground() ) { 
        if(invoke(paintBackground, object_wrap(gfx)) == TRUE_VALUE)
           return; // default background drawing was suppressed by script
      }
      default_draw_background(gfx);
   }
}
```

In this case script may draw something underneath element's background layer, on top of it, or even completely instead of default renderer.

UPDATE:

Scripting object produced by object_wrap(gfx) is connected to real rendering surface only inside rendering calls. Any attempt to store and use that gfx object somewhere else will throw an error: "invalid rendering surface".

I am not sure but suspect that you need something like this.

Comment: Well this does not have any advantage over directly programming the render loop in C++. There should be a way to inject a javascript function into the main loop and manipulate it during the runtime. I am more looking for a solution to make the render loop "truly" script-able. like in a browser.

Comment: If you want to get an answer you should explain what exactly "
render loop "truly" script-able. like in a browser" is in your mind.

Sample that I've provided is *exactly* how browser handles drawing - in response of WM_PAINT and the like messages.

Comment: In your example, you have a class, Element. I am assuming there is a master Element-manager in your code that goes around and calls drawBackground of its children, right? That means you already have a logic inside of your main render loop, which is drawing individual drawBackground methods. In my case, that logic needs to be implemented in Javascript, not C++.

Comment: In browser: you have `<canvas>` element. That `<canvas>` has bitmap backed Graphics associated with it. You are getting graphics object reference from that `<canvas>`. You draw on it using Graphics primitives. In its WM_PAINT handler (or any time it needs to render the DOM) it draws that bitmap buffer underneath the <canvas> as its content. This is how browser implements that drawing. And question is: what exactly here, you think, is that ""truly" script-able render loop" ?

Comment: I think reading this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/
would be beneficial to start with.

Comment: <canvas> element is exactly what I am trying to implement in pure C++, however the graphics engine behind it uses libcairo and openGL and has a super class that has a virtual draw method, I can never touch the drawing mechanics of the engine unless I am living inside that draw method. I want the user of my program gains the ability to override that draw method in Javascript.

Comment: As I said: 1) you need to create bitmap. 2) Then to get cairo surface for it http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html . 3) provide scriptable wrapper for that surface that will be used anytime you want. In that virtual draw method of yours - just draw that bitmap in its current state.